What "other Peter" is Miles referring to?
At a restaurant scene in Spider-Man Into the Spider-Verse (2018) Alternate Universe Cut, Miles and Peter B. Parker are discussing the events
that occurred during the first test of the Super Collider.

Miles: So when the other Peter got shoved in the collider beam by
the freaky giant green dude...
Peter B. Parker : That event created a portal that brought me here.

Actually, during the first test of the Super Collider, Miles, hiding under the rubble,
witnessed Kingpin deliver a killing blow to Peter Parker and escaped when
Kingpin ordered Prowler to kill him
What "other Peter" is Miles referring to ?

Miles is talking about this happening, where Spider-Man is thrown into the collider beam by Green Goblin:



Miles calls him the "other Peter" in this conversation to differentiate from the one he is currently talking to.
